# Is Intrusion Detection ( XSS attacks ) a cross cutting concern? Can we decouple it with AOP's?

Tags: java, struts, xss, aop, cross-cutting-concerns

I am currently working on to safeguard application from **XSS attacks**. So I am checking that particularly for **Every Request**. This also can be checked at interceptors level.

But I want to decouple it with something like AOP's?

Any input from your experience is appreciable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a Filter is the easiest way to do this task, AOP is useful when you don't have any easy way to add transversal behavior/ functionality, but in this precise case is unnecessary.
You can check how common it is just googling "java xss filter", there are plenty of examples.

Comment: +1 for adding a filter. I would totally do both XSS and XSRF prevention checks in a filter.